# HttpWebRequest GetResponse times out second time through

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

So I have a list of URLs that I'm processing through and in a couple of cases I run into an argument exception due to `gzip encoding` issues, so I drew up this code to resolve the `gzip encoding` problems.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
req.Method = "GET";
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))";
string source;

using (WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse())
// On the second iteration we never get beyond this line
{
    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = webResponse as HttpWebResponse;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        source = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    httpWebResponse.Close();
}

req.Abort();
```

This works for the first URL that needs this processing.  however the second URL that needs processing times out.  I'm not sure what it is that I'm missing to get this to work consistently.

Now I do have the URLs being sent to the above method inside a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (string uri in _UriAddresses)
{
    ProcessListItem(uri);
}
```

Let me know if there's anything that's not shown that would shed light on this issue.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders  Thank you for the heads up on that.  I will do my best to keep that in mind for future questions.